# Execute shell script whithin another script prompts: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

(I'm new in shell script.)

I've been stuck with this issue for a while. I've tried different methods but without luck.

Description:

When my script attempt to run another script (`SiebelMessageCreator.sh`, which I don't own) it prompts:

```
-bash: ./SiebelMessageCreator.sh: No such file or directory
```

But the file exists and has execute permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner ownergrp      322 Jun 11  2015 SiebelMessageCreator.sh
```

The code that is performing the script execution is:

```
(cd $ScriptPath; su -c './SiebelMessageCreator.sh' - owner; su -c 'nohup sh SiebelMessageSender.sh &' - owner;)
```

It's within a subshell because I first thought that it was throwing that message because my script was running in my home directory (When I run the script I'm root and I've moved to my non-root home directory to run the script because I can't move my script [ policies ] to the directory where the other script resides).

I've also tried with the `sh SCRIPT.sh` `./SCRIPT.sh`. And changing the shebang from bash to ksh because the SiebelMessageCreator.sh has that shell.

The `su -c 'sh SCRIPT.sh' - owner` is necessary. If the script runs as root and not as owner it brokes something (?) (that's what my partners told me from their experience executing it as root). So I execute it as the owner.

Another thing that I've found in my research is that It can throw that message if it's a Symbolic link. I'm really not sure if the content of the script it's a symbolic link. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
BASEDIRROOT=/path/to/file/cpp-plwsutil-c
ore-runtime.jar (path changed on purpose for this question)

java -classpath $BASEDIRROOT com.hp.cpp.plwsutil.SiebelMessageCreator

exitCode=$?

echo "`date -u '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` - Script execution finished with exit code $exitCode."
exit $exitCode
```

As you can see it's a very siple script that just call a .jar. But also I can't add it to my script [ policies ].

If I run the `./SiebelMessageCreator.sh` manually it works just fine. But not with my script. I suppose that discards the x64 x32 bits issue that I've also found when I googled?

By the way, I'm automating some tasks, the `./SiebelMessageCreator.sh` and `nohup sh SiebelMessageSender.sh &` are just the last steps.

Any ideas :( ?

Comment: calling scripts by using `sh scriptName` just complicates the matter. Either add `PATH="/path/to/special/scripts:$PATH"` to your executing environment OR just use full paths (or envVars of full Paths) to call your scripts, ie. `/path/to/SiebelMsgCent.sh`. Good luck.

Comment: Assuming that the script is indeed in the home directory of the owner, there are 2 things you should check. The filename `SiebelMessageCreator.sh` does not contain a non-printing character. Or check that your script doesn't contain non-printing character within the filename `SiebelMessageCreator.sh`. I strongly suggest use a fully qualified path or add the path to your `PATH` as suggested by @shellter.

Comment: I must add, `cd $ScriptPath` will be ignored because `-` in the command `su` means use the login shell therefore the child process will be spawned in the owner's home directory. If the script you are calling is indeed in `$ScriptPath`, you can either omit `-` or use fully qualified path to the script.

Comment: @alvits Thank you very much. Indeed, the `cd $ScriptPath` was being ignored. I've tested with a few `pwd` outside and inside the `su`. And the child process was being spawned in the owner's home directory. First I tried with the full path as suggested by @shellter but it was throwing a java error. Then I figured it out that I needed to `cd $ScriptPath` inside the `su`. At the end it worked like this: `(su -c 'cd /path/to/script; ./SiebelMessageCreator.sh' - owner)`. :)! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

did you try ?

```
. ./SiebelMessageCreator.sh
```

you can also perform `which sh` or `which ksh`, then modify the first line `#!/bin/ksh`